# Is struct of strings the same as array of strings?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, casting

I'm dealing with code, that has multiple structures consisting of `string`-fields only. For example:

```
struct record {
    string first;
    string second;
    string third;

    string Nth;
};
```

These are currently all loaded from a database and stored in different `map<string, somestruct>` -- with a separate method for each. The methods are the same (except for the SQL-queries and field-names) -- the first field of each query becomes the map's index, and the subsequent ones form the structure's fields:

```
void
LoadFoo()
{
    rows = RunSQLQuery("SELECT key, first, second FROM sometable");
    for (auto row = rows.cbegin(); row != rows.cend(); row++) {
        struct record r = {
            first = row[1];
            second = row[2];
        };
        Foos.insert(make_pair(row[0], r));
    }
}
```

I'd like to unify these methods into one, capable of initializing structures with different number of fields -- and differing field-names.

This new method will receive the SQL-query to run and the (empty) `map`. The method will know the total number of fields the query returns, but it would not be able to refer to individual fields *by name* -- only by sequence number.

Which would be Ok, **if the above structures can be safely cast into `string[N]`. Can they?**

(No, I don't want to change from `struct`s to arrays "officially", because the field-names are meaningful where they are actually used throughout the rest of the application.)

Comment: Short answer: no they cannot. C++ does not work this way. It's possible that if you do it today it might appear to work, but tomorrow everything will crash. This is what's called "undefined behavior".

Comment: I seem to recall this being valid in C... Any other way to enumerate through fields of a structure -- suppose my method is `template`-ized with the structure's type being the template's argument...

Comment: Undefined behaviour, as mentioend by Sam. You might be able to solve this with templates or the preprocessor tho...

Comment: For example, `template<size_t N> struct record { ... } ;` But it's difficult to help when your problem is so abstract.

Comment: Just emulate it by adding `operator[]` and write an iterator.

Comment: @TonyK, the size-part is easy -- but how do I iterate through fields in the structure? @tadman, how would the `[]` refer to individual fields of the structure generically? I'd rather avoid a custom such operator for each :(

Comment: "These are currently all loaded from a database and stored in different `map<string, somestruct>`": this is so vague that I can't see how to help you. You must be more specific.

Comment: @TonyK, I edited the question to give an example of a method currently in use.

Answer (score 3):

You can have *references* to an array for the named members like this:

```
struct record {
    std::string items[3];
    std::string& first = items[0];
    std::string& second = items[1];
    std::string& third = items[2];
};

int main()
{
    record r{"a", "b", "c"};

    std::cout << r.first << ' ' << r.second << ' ' << r.third << '\n';
}
```

**Output:**

```
a b c
```

Comment: Aliasing? That's nice! It should not increase the structures' sizes, does it?

Comment: @MikhailT. It is implementation dependant if it increases the size. You can't rely on the sizes of structs in `C++`.

Comment: This is guaranteed to increase the size of the structure, which means that an array of these structures will not be layout-compatible with a flat array of strings.

Comment: Also, can the referencing be _dynamic_ -- determined at run time?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Arrays of structures are not guaranteed to be layout-compatible with a flat array anyway because of padding.

Comment: To reduce the structure size use `std::string& first() { return items[0]; }` etc.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik it's not guaranteed, although it is likely

Comment: another thing to consider: this will make your structure non-copyable (assignment) due to the reference data member.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following is technically UB, but should [work](https://godbolt.org/z/hxz9Y4) under common implementations, and most cases where it doesn't should be caught at compile time by `static_assert`.

```
#include <string>

struct List { std::string a0, a1; };
struct Array { std::string a[2]; };

union Overlay {
     List ll;
     Array aa;

     Overlay() : aa() { }
     ~Overlay() { aa.~Array(); }
};

static_assert(sizeof(List) == sizeof(Array));
static_assert(offsetof(List, a0) == offsetof(Array, a[0]));
static_assert(offsetof(List, a1) == offsetof(Array, a[1]));

void foo() {
    Overlay la;    
static_assert(&la.ll.a0 == &la.aa.a[0]);
static_assert(&la.ll.a1 == &la.aa.a[1]);
}
```

Comment: I suppose, I could calculate the right offset for the second field, and use that figure to iterate through the rest of them too, eh?

Comment: @MikhailT. Why would you need to do that? Once you have the `Overlay la;` you can access the individual strings via `la.ll.a#` and the array as `la.aa.a` with usual array indexing.

Comment: 'cause I don't want to rename things in the rest of the application :( But your answer seems to suggest, what I'm looking for is generally possible today -- and the `static_assert` gives a way to catch an incompatibility going forward.

Comment: @MikhailT. You don't have to touch anything outside your code. And in your code just cast any `List` reference to an `Overlay` reference (or directly to an `Array` reference, for that matter). Again, this is not the most by-the-book way to do it, but it should work as long as no `static_assert` fails.

Comment: It's still a union / object lifetime mistake even if the `static_assert` doesn't fire

Comment: @M.M That's stated in the very beginning: "*is technically UB*".

Comment: You go on to say that the static_assert would catch cases where it doesn't work though

Comment: @M.M Changed that to "***most*** *cases*" now. If you disagree please point to a "*common implementation*" where that fails.

Comment: I doubt there is any implementation where the `static_assert` would fire

Comment: @M.M I'd be surprised if it did. That said, it's a fair warning to know when crossing the line.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advise against *all* casting shenanigans! In fact, I don't actually believe there's a standard-compliant way to get `struct` with named fields that you can also cast into an array. But the thing is, in your problem, it doesn't look like you *need* the structures to be cast to arrays. You can made do just fine with a template.

```
// this definition should not be directly referenced but needs to be included in every file that indirectly uses it anyway
// convention is to stick it in some namespace where no one will touch it
namespace detail {
    template<typename T, std::size_t... Ns>
    void Load(std::map<std::string, T> &sink, char const *query, std::index_sequence<Ns...>) {
        for(auto const &row : RunSQLQuery(query)) sink.insert(std::make_pair(row[0], T{row[Ns + 1]...}));
    }
}
template<typename T, std::size_t NFields>
void Load(std::map<std::string, T> &sink, char const *query) {
    detail::Load(sink, query, std::make_index_sequence<NFields>());
}
```

You pass the number of fields to `Load`, `make_index_sequence` expands that into the list of indices `0, 1, ..., NFields-1`, and then `detail::Load` constructs the records by `record{row[1], row[2], ..., row[NFields]}`. Assuming the `record`s really do look as you've written in the question, with no constructors, then they are considered aggregates, and the `{expr1, expr2, ..., exprn}` syntax simply initializes the fields in order. You do have to remember the number of fields at each call to `Load`, which may be bad. I think there's some horrible template magic you can do to autodetect the number of fields, but if it's a concern and you don't want to do that, I would just write the number of fields into each class:

```
struct record {
    std::string first, second, third;
    static constexpr std::size_t n_fields = 3;
};
```

and set `NFields = T::n_fields` as the default in the `template`.

In C++11, you can define `index_sequence` and `make_index_sequence` even though they are absent from the standard library

```
template<std::size_t...>
struct index_sequence { };
namespace detail {
    template<std::size_t>
    struct make_index_sequence_impl;
}
template<std::size_t N>
using make_index_sequence = typename detail::make_index_sequence_impl<N>::type;
namespace detail {
    template<>
    struct make_index_sequence_impl<0> {
        using type = index_sequence<>;
    };
    template<std::size_t N>
    struct make_index_sequence_impl {
        template<typename>
        struct helper;
        template<std::size_t... Ns>
        struct helper<index_sequence<Ns...>> {
            using type = index_sequence<Ns..., N - 1>;
        };
        using type = typename helper<make_index_sequence<N - 1>>::type;
    };
}
```

Comment: The number of fields is of the least concern - I can get it from the query (and the type of each field too, BTW). It is the initialization of `T`-structure inside the `make_pair`, that I don't understand -- you have the `...` in there -- can you provide a working example instead? Thanks!

Comment: @MikhailT. [It works as is](https://godbolt.org/z/5cq4YW). It is a pack expansion: the pattern `row[Ns + 1]` is wrapped around each value of `Ns`, producing a list, and that list is plugged into the code separated by commas.

Comment: Very interesting... And C+=11 supports this?!

Comment: @MikhailT. The *language* supports it fine. The *library* is missing `index_sequence`, but that doesn't matter since it's trivial to implement. [Here it is](https://godbolt.org/z/9h1zs4) compiling under `-std=c++11`.

Comment: Ohp, just like me to call something trivial and then have an off-by-one error. [Here it is](https://godbolt.org/z/ToK5c9) actually *executing* without error.

Comment: Thank you for the functioning examples, @HTNW. I admit, I find them too complex for the simple case of `string`-only structures, which are really arrays (stern talk of UB notwithstanding). However, I feel, your constructs can also be used for records with fields of different types (say, a mix of `string` and `double`) -- where simply casting to an array will not work. Can they?

Comment: @MikhailT. Write a constructor for the class that takes however many strings and parses some of them to whatever type, I suppose.