# Is there a way to access a the nth element of a struct?

Tags: c++, struct, types

I have struct of pointers where the pointers are of arbitrary type but are known at compile time.

```
struct ptrs
{
    int* a;
    const char** b;
    int* c;
    float* d;
};
```

Given they are all pointers they will all be the same length. Is there a way that I can access the nth element with type information.

I could cast the struct to a void pointer array but then I'd lose knowledge of what type I'm looking at, likewise with using a union.

The entire code base is in c++20 so I don't need to worry about c support.

Edit: I want this for the following use. I will create a variadic macro to convert an arbitrary number of inputs into an array of pointers to then. This will be passed to a function for processing which will process them in an arbitrary order according to a command string. E.G. "return $var1 + $var2". The processing requires random access to elements one or more times, hence "indexing" a struct. However for the support of arithmetic the type need to be known.

Comment: What's the ultimate goal of this exercise? What are you really trying to achieve? Your question sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/); it doesn't make much sense on its own.

Comment: C++ doesn't support reflection.

Comment: Believe it or not, this is actually easier to guarantee with C.

Comment: In what form are you expecting to get the type, if n is only known at runtime how could the compiler possibly give you that?

Comment: Related: [Is struct of strings the same as array of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65376065/is-struct-of-strings-the-same-as-array-of-strings/).

Comment: Using `std::tuple` (directly of via conversion) might help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. Some of the code is a little tricky to write, but [Boost PFR](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_pfr.html) has already done the heavy lifting, so you could do something like:

```cpp
ptrs p;

float * f = boost::pfr::get<3>(p); // get the `float *` member
*f = 123.4f;                       // and write via the pointer
```

[Note that I've only broken this into two lines so I can comment each step--something like `*boost::pfr::get<3>(p) = 123.4f;` should be fine as well.]

For anybody who cares, the basic idea of how you do this is *fairly* simple--it's only the details that get tricky.

The basic approach is to use structured binding to get the item you care about. The trickiness comes from a couple of sources: you don't know what type(s) you're dealing with, and the types are vary, so it's not as simple as creating an array of items and indexing into the array.

But still, simplifying quite a bit, we can do something like this:

```cpp
template <std::size_t index>
constexpr auto& get(auto& your_struct)
{
    auto& [zero, one, two, three] = your_struct;

    if constexpr (index == 0)
        return zero;
    if constexpr (index == 1)
        return one;
    if constexpr (index == 2)
        return two;
    return three;
}
```

I'll repeat: I'm simplifying a fair amount (e.g., I've just used a fixed number of members) but that's at least roughly the general idea--use a structured binding to grab members, and a constexpr condition to choose which one you care about, with template parameters (in the form of `auto`) for essentially all the pieces, so you can deal with whatever types happen to be there.

Oh, there's one more detail that's just a *little* tricky to deal with: as it stands, this implementation can only work for one type. That is, if you try to use `get<0>` and `get<3>`, you'll get an error about inconsistency in the deduced return type. So as it stands at the moment, you can use `get<0>` *or* `get<2>` (or whatever), but not both, so it's purely a limited proof of concept thing, not a practical implementation (at all).

Here's a working demo program though:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

struct ptrs {
    int* a;
    const char** b;
    int* c;
    float* d;
};

template <std::size_t index>
constexpr auto& get(auto& your_struct)
{
    auto& [zero, one, two, three] = your_struct;

    if constexpr (index == 0)
        return zero;
    if constexpr (index == 1)
        return one;
    if constexpr (index == 2)
        return two;
    return three;
}

int main() {
    ptrs p;
    p.d = new float; // `get<3>(p) = new float;` works fine too.

    *get<3>(p) = 123.4;
    
    // show we're accessing the same data either way:
    std::cout << *get<3>(p) << "\t" << *(p.d) << "\n";

    // type information is retained. For example, if we try to do this:
    // get<3>(p) = new int;  // <-- note int instead of float
    // g++ 10 gives the error: "cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘float*’ in assignment"
}
```

Comment: while interesting, I'm not sure how this approach got marked as the answer since it requires compile-time knowledge of `n`. the question, as clarified, requires access to n determined by string input at runtime

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way, without concocting a bunch of metadata machinery.

```
void* get(ptrs const& data, int n)
{
    // TODO: add checks
    return ((void**)&data)[n];
}
```

You should note that the standard doesn't guarantee that all data pointers are the same size.  However, on most architectures, they are.  So consult your compiler documentation, or use a `static_assert` to confirm it.

Comment: This be [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) of the "Probably work" sort. Remember to watch out for hidden metadata in more complicated data structures.